# Uppercase all columns in all table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I originally created tables in snowflake, I used quotes around the column names, which has made things case sensitive for subsequent auto-generated queries. All new table are now created with uppercase column names, so the new queries work fine. Is there a way I can convert all column names to uppercase in all tables in Snowflake?

Comment: You mean to say whey you created the tables you created them in lower or mixed case as Snowflake stores the table names in uppercase unless you quote ("") the names when you create the objects. If you want to change from lower/mixed case to Upper case then one way would be to ALTER table table_name rename column old_col to new_col;

Comment: Yes,  that is it.  The problem is,  there are a lot of tables and columns and I was looking for a script that would trawl through all the tables and columns and apply the changes,  without me writing it for each column manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed this by doing the following, to generate a load of ALTER TABLE commands:

```
    select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' RENAME COLUMN "', COLUMN_NAME, '" to ', UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), ';')
from information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ilike 'SchemaName'
AND COLUMN_NAME != UPPER(COLUMN_NAME)
```

Comment: Hi Slicc! Thanks for sharing. However it didn't throw me the outputs whenI tried to use the code you listed. is there anything I'm missing here?